# how to use char ** properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have two examples, which of these two is better and why? In both cases, I got the same result. I have chosen container simply to hold strings.

```
Example 1:

    char *c_ptr[] = {};
    int num;
    if (fill_array(c_ptr, &num) != 0) {
          cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       cout << "Str[" << i << "] = " << c_ptr[i] << endl;
    } 
    // free pointer..

    // Function implementation 
    int fill_array(char *c_ptr[], int *count) {
        vector<string> v = {"haha", "hehe", "omg", "happy, learning!"};
        *count = v.size();
        int i = 0;

        for (vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++, i++) {
            c_ptr[i] = (char*)malloc((*it).size() + 1);
            strncpy(c_ptr[i], (*it).c_str(),(*it).size() + 1);
        }
        return 0;
    }


Example 2:

    char **c_ptr = NULL;
    int num;
    if (fill_array(&c_ptr, &num) != 0) {
          cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       cout << "Str[" << i << "] = " << c_ptr[i] << endl;
    } 
    // free double pointer..

    // Function implementation 
    int fill_array(char ***c_ptr, int *num) {
        vector<string> v = {"haha", "hehe", "omg", "happy, learning!"};
        *num = v.size();
        int i = 0;

        *c_ptr = (char **)malloc(*num * sizeof(char *));
        for (vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++, i++) {
            c_ptr[i] = (char*)malloc((*it).size() + 1);
            strncpy(*c_ptr[i], (*it).c_str(),(*it).size() + 1);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**Result**:

```
Str[0] = haha
Str[1] = hehe
Str[2] = omg
Str[3] = happy, learning!
```

Also What is the use of empty bracket in array? Is it good programming habit vs dynamic allocation?

Comment: If you want to learn C++, `std::vector<std::string>` is the idiomatic way to have a collection of strings.

Comment: In C++? Then the proper way is to *not* use it, and instead use a vector of strings.

Comment: I know. In C how can we do this? Sorry, will add C folks too. I chose this container to simple hold bunch of strings. I should have written pure C code.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but don't use `strncpy` here. You've already figured out how many characters you need, and allocated an appropriate memory block. If you messed up, `strncpy`will leave you with a character array that's not nul terminated, and later code will mysteriously die. `strncpy` is **not** a "safe" replacement for `strcpy` for any reasonable definition of "safe".

Comment: Sure, thanks @PeteBecker. I will use strdup instead.

Comment: If you are using C++, do not use malloc. Stick to new and delete.

Comment: By the way, the examples are not clear. what is str_list? What do you mean "same result"? I suspect that your program should crash at some point. You address c_ptr[i] before allocating memory for it.

Comment: Fixed and added the result @Makketronix. Thank you!

Comment: There's little related to C here. I've removed the C tag. Which book are you reading?

Comment: @Makketronix Actually, I'd say: if you are using C++, do not use raw malloc/free or new/delete, stick to smart pointers or standard containers such as `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** is pointer to a pointer or simply we can say it a double pointer.

Double pointers are better to use when we are passing a pointer variable from main() or simply a function to another function.

By looking at your code, I would like to suggest you one thing and that is, avoid using global variables.

Comment: Sure  @Jorvis, I will keep this in mind. What do you think for this example? Which approach is better to go with Example 1 or Example 2?

Comment: Can we define char pointer array without any size and then add elements later like I did in my example or it is better to define dynamic array?

Comment: -> I would say Example 2 is better to go with.

Comment: -> I would suggest that dynamic array i.e. making an array using pointers is better because pointers also helps us increasing the performance of the code as compiler has to work a little less in case of pointers because when we declare array as array[] then internally it gets converted into pointer form only.